# Split column to multiple fields using R

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, stringr, text-analysis

I have a column in my csv which has a field "features". The fields has data in this format

```
{""Air conditioning"",""Elevator"",""Smoke detector""}
{""Air conditioning"",""Railing Lights"",""Smoke detector""}
{""Air conditioning"",""Washer"",""Dryer"",""Smoke detector""}
```

Their are 20000 records with these strings inside the field "features" that are not in any particular order.

How can I split them to different columns in a way that all "Air conditioning" all fall under 1st column,"elevators" under 2nd and so on.

```
          a          b       c              d            
air conditioning elevators smokedetectors 
air conditioning elevators smokedetectors washer
air conditioning elevators smokedetectors washer
```

Comment: check `?cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package.

Comment: You could just use `read.csv(text = gsub('[{}]', '', txt), 
         header = FALSE, 
         quote = '""')` where `txt` is the text above as a single string

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `separate` from `tidyr` and `mutate_at` from `dplyr` (with a `gsub` thrown in):

```
dfr <- data.frame(features = c('{""Air conditioning"",""Elevator"",""Smoke detector""}',
                               '{""Air conditioning"",""Railing Lights"",""Smoke detector""}',
                               '{""Air conditioning"",""Washer"",""Dryer"",""Smoke detector""}'))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# Remove {,}, and quotes (")
fix_txt <- function(x)gsub("[{]\"|\"|[}]", "", x)
separate(dfr, features, c("a","b","c"), sep=",", extra="merge") %>%
mutate_at(vars(a:c), fix_txt)
```

gives

```
                 a              b                    c
1 Air conditioning       Elevator       Smoke detector
2 Air conditioning Railing Lights       Smoke detector
3 Air conditioning         Washer Dryer,Smoke detector
```

Note that extra fields are merged (as in the third record), look at `?separate` for more options.

Comment: Thank you. Just if you would notice in your output column B has elevator as 1st and washer in 3rd. What could be done to get all washers under one column, all elevators under another column.

Comment: Your original question did not really indicate that! I think we'd have to rethink the solution altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can look at the "splitstackshape" package, specifically, the `cSplit_e` function. With it, you can try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(as.data.table(dfr)[, features := (gsub("[{}\"]", "", features))], 
         "features", ",", mode = "value", type = "character", drop = TRUE)
##    features_Air conditioning features_Dryer features_Elevator features_Railing Lights features_Smoke detector features_Washer
## 1:          Air conditioning             NA          Elevator                      NA          Smoke detector              NA
## 2:          Air conditioning             NA                NA          Railing Lights          Smoke detector              NA
## 3:          Air conditioning          Dryer                NA                      NA          Smoke detector          Washer
```

Where "dfr" is defined as in @Remko's answer:

```
dfr <- data.frame(features = c('{""Air conditioning"",""Elevator"",""Smoke detector""}',
                               '{""Air conditioning"",""Railing Lights"",""Smoke detector""}',
                               '{""Air conditioning"",""Washer"",""Dryer"",""Smoke detector""}'))
```